# Parity of some binomial coefficients

Tags: binomial-coefficients, parity

Consider for fixed integer $n>1$  the binomial coefficients $\binom{n-1+2^j}{n+1-2^j}$ for $j>0.$
It seems that precisely one of these numbers is odd. 
Is there a simple proof of this fact?

Comment: Hmm, it depends on what you mean by "simple". I see an inductive argument. Recall that $\dbinom{2a}{2b} \equiv \dbinom{2a+1}{2b+1} \equiv \dbinom{a}{b} \mod 2$ for all nonnegative integers $a$ and $b$. Thus, $\dbinom{n-1+2^j}{n+1-2^j} \equiv \dbinom{m+2^{j-1}}{m+1-2^{j-1}} \mod 2$, where $m = \left\lfloor \dfrac{n-1}{2} \right\rfloor$. Thus, it remains to prove that for each nonnegative integer $m$, there is exactly one nonnegative integer $i$ such that $\dbinom{m+2^i}{m+1-2^i}$ is odd. This can be proven by strong induction on $m$, where ...

Comment: ... the induction step uses the facts that $\dbinom{2a}{2b+1} \equiv 0 \mod 2$ and $\dbinom{2a+1}{2b} \equiv \dbinom{a}{b} \mod 2$ for all nonnegative integers $a$ and $b$. There is probably a slicker way to put this -- maybe using generating functions?

Comment: Ah, I see how to compute this unique $i$ (non-inductively): Write $m$ in binary as $m = m_k 2^k + m_{k-1} 2^{k-1} + \cdots + m_0 2^0$ with all $m_h$ belonging to $\left\{0,1\right\}$. Then, $i$ is the smallest $h$ such that $m_h = 0$. This can be easily checked using Lucas's theorem (though the inductive proof still has the advantage of being easier to write up).

Comment: Thank you. Nice proof.